# Adding year from input to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page A that has a form with an input for year and a drop down for month.

```
            <form method="post" action="" name="form_cal" id="form_cal" class="inputform">
                <div class="h5"><strong>Total Number of People Registered:</strong> <?Php echo $totalpersons; ?></div>
                <div class="clear_5"></div>
                <div>
                    <span><label class="h5"><strong>Year *</strong></label></span>
                    <div class="clear_1"></div>
                    <span><input name="year" type="text" class="textbox" id="year" required></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><label class="h5"><strong>Month for Screening</strong></label></span>
                    <span>                          
                        <select name="month" id="month" value="" tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true" required style="height:50px;display: block;padding:10px;" class="h5">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">- Select One -</option>
                            <option value="1">January</option>
                            <option value="2">Febuary</option>
                            <option value="3">March</option>
                            <option value="4">April</option>
                            <option value="5">May</option>
                            <option value="6">June</option>
                            <option value="7">July</option>
                            <option value="8">August</option>
                            <option value="9">September</option>
                            <option value="10">October</option>
                            <option value="11">November</option>
                            <option value="12">December</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I also have another page B that gets all days in the month selected on page A via ajax.

If i use the date function for year, `date("Y");` it works fine. i get all days of the month for the specified month. But the date function for year is only for the current year. 
What i want to achieve is be able to enter a year in the input field for year and when the ajax is called, the value of the year in the input field is passed to the ajax so as to display the days of the selected month for the year specified.
Below is my ajax call ( i think this is where i need to make the adjustment. but can't figure out the best way to do it)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var timer = null; 
  var dataString; 
  function submitForm(){
      $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "cim-calendar-action.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#calendar-display').html(result);
                }
      });
      return false;
  }
  $('#month').on('change', function() {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     var month = $(this).val();
     dataString = 'month='+ month;
     timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
 });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Get the value of the input using `.val()` and add it to the `dataString` to pass it through to Page B via Ajax, simples.

Comment: @Studocwho i tried that but could not get it to work. I set the `dataString` to `dataString = 'month='+ month + '&year=' year;` but i did not get desired result.

Comment: and getting the value of the year using: `var year = document.getElementById("year").value;`

Comment: What wasn't the desired result? Did `year` have the stored year value?

Comment: why oh why are you defining `var dataString` in a scope it's not needed in? `timer = setTimeout(function(){submitForm(dataString)}, 050);` and `function submitForm(dataString){` your current way your just asking for a mid flight collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further reading and testing, i was able to solve it. Thanks to @Studocwho for the direction. And thanks to others who commented and suggested a solution. This is my working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var timer = null; 
    var dataString; 
    function submitForm(){
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                    url: "cim-calendar-action.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(result){
                        $('#calendar-display').html(result);
                    }
        });
        return false;
    }
    $('#month').on('change', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        var month = $(this).val();
        var year = $("#year").val();
        dataString = {'month': month, 'year': year };
        timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
    });
});
```

I added `var year = $("#year").val();` and changed the datastring to `dataString = {'month': month, 'year': year };`

Answer (score 0):

For the javascript I would suggest something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var timer = null;
        var dataObj = Object();
        function submitForm(){
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "cim-calendar-action.php",
                data: {dateObj: JSON.stringify(dataObj)},
                success: function(result){
                    $('#calendar-display').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        $('#month').on('change', function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            var month = $(this).val();
            dataObj.month = month;
            dataObj.year = $('#year').val();
            timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
        });
    });
```

And then to get the info from php you just get it like this:

```
$dateObj = json_decode($_POST['dateObj']);
echo $dateObj->month.'/'.$dateObj->year;
```

For the date function, you need to pass in a second parameter with the info on what year you want to specify

Read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php